# How to run a AUTOHOTKEY file/script and save it for ever?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I created a AutoHotkey file for few modifacations to my keyboard, if i double click the file the modificatoins are working. ex. '1' becomes 'a'
When I restart the comptuer the modifications are not remembered and I need to run again the file to save the modification. How to save the file forever and make it work without run the script every time I turn off the computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Task Scheduler (taskschd.msc in system32) to make your script autorun at startup, even silently with elevated privileges, if that's a requirement.

Comment: I put in the folder of the start app a the end. Thanks for the idea